# atoi to place part of string into array[0]

Tags: c, arrays, string, atoi

I'm taking in input from the user as a string. I want to transfer the input to an integer array. I'm using `atoi`, but it places the entire input from the user into each part of the integer array. How do I get this to happen:

```
string input = 12345
array[0] = 1
array[1] = 2 
array[2] = 3
etc.
```

Instead of:

```
string input = 12345 
array[0] = 12345
array[1] = 12345
array[2] = 12345
etc.
```

Comment: This doesn't look like valid C code. Can you please post the code you have written so far?

Comment: Yes, please show your code, or at least tell us how `array` is declared.

Answer (score 1):

In stead of using `atoi` you should convert each digit separately to an integer value and place it in the array.

As a normality of ASCII, the ASCII digits are consequtive, so you can use:

```
    char c = '9';
    array[1] = c - '0';
```

As this smells of homework, I leave the rest to you. I hope this helps.